# Changing the icons onclick jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the icon when I click on it, my code does not work

```js
$(document).ready(function chevxx(i) {
  if ($("a#a" + i + ".collapsed")) {
    $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
  } else {
    $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" class="collapsed" onclick="chevxx(0)"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your `chevxx` function in the wrong place. Also, even if you had written the jQuery `ready` function properly, anything declared inside it like your `chevxx` function, will not be accessible from the HTML (`onclick="chevxx(0)"`), because it's scoped.

Seems like it would be best to first learn javascript fundamentals before attempting to write javascript code, even the simplest one might be tricky without fundamentals.

### jQuery [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function chevxx(i){...}
});
```

---

Further reading:

### [JavaScript Scope and Closures](https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: chevxx is not defined

Comment: just as I had said.

Answer (score 0):

`chevxx` function can't be accessed because you declared it in other function's scope, therefore it's not visible where you need it to be.

If you want it to work with `onclick=""` you have to move your callback function declaration to global scope, meaning moving it outside of jQuery's `ready` function.

```
function chevxx(i) {...}
$(document).ready(function () {...})
```

Other solution would be to get rid of `onclick=""` inside html and replace it with attaching events programmatically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function chevxx(i) {...}
    $('#a0').click(chevxx(0));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery's `click()` EventListener method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a0").click(function(){
     if ($("a#a0.collapsed")) {
         $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>");
     } 
     else {
         $(this).append("<i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and get rid of onclick=chevxx(0)

Comment: there are reasons why. you cannot possibly know the OP's setup and when and where his code is being loaded, therefor your solution merely suggests all the HTML is accessible via JS at the time the JS had run, and such assumption should not be made lightly.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written `chevxx` is part of `ready` method callback.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').bind('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapse')) {
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-right');
      $(this).removeClass('collapse');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('collapse');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-right').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-down');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" class="collapsed"><i class='fa fa-chevron-circle-down'></i></a>
```

From your question i can understand that you are using bootstrap's collapsible. Why don't you use bootstraps events for toggling icons.

e.g.

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-right').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-down');
})
.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-right');
});
```

ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-events